# Descriptive statistics for factors/summarizing factors from a dataset in a long format using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, categorical-data

I have data on repeated measurements, currently in a long format.

What I want to do is just to get some summary statistics like counts and percentages per timepoint.

Example data:

```
questiondata <- structure(list(id = c(2, 2, 6, 6, 9, 9, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 25, 
30, 30, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 34), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("time1", "time2"), class = "factor"), age = c(65, 
69.17, 76.75, 81.05, 58.64, 62.71, 59.37, 63.56, 58, 61.69, 55.78, 
59.95, 59.3, 63.36, 60.45, 64.39, 56.3, 60.08, 59.53, 63.84), 
    sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("men", 
    "women"), class = "factor"), hypert_drug = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which corresponds to the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
      id time    age sex   hypert_drug
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <fct>      
 1     2 time1  65   men   no         
 2     2 time2  69.2 men   yes        
 3     6 time1  76.8 women yes        
 4     6 time2  81.0 women yes        
 5     9 time1  58.6 men   no         
 6     9 time2  62.7 men   no         
 7    22 time1  59.4 men   no         
 8    22 time2  63.6 men   no         
 9    23 time1  58   women no         
10    23 time2  61.7 women no         
11    25 time1  55.8 men   no         
12    25 time2  60.0 men   no         
13    30 time1  59.3 women no         
14    30 time2  63.4 women yes        
15    31 time1  60.4 men   yes        
16    31 time2  64.4 men   yes        
17    33 time1  56.3 men   no         
18    33 time2  60.1 men   no         
19    34 time1  59.5 women no         
20    34 time2  63.8 women no
```

I have tried the following to get simple count of men and women:

```
questiondata %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarise(n_sex=n_distinct(sex))
```

But that gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  time  n_sex
* <fct> <int>
1 time1     2
2 time2     2
```

And then I tried

```
questiondata %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(n_sex=count(sex))
```

Which gives an error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `n_sex`.
x no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "factor"
i Input `n_sex` is `count(sex)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: time = "time1".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Shortcut for group_by %>% summarize:  `questiondata %>% count(time, sex, name = "n_sex")`

Answer (score 1):

This uses both time and sex as grouping variables, and the n column represents the number of observations for each combination of time and sex.

```
library(dplyr)

 questiondata %>% 
    group_by(time, sex) %>% 
    summarize(n=n())

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'time'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   time [2]
  time  sex       n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 time1 men       6
2 time1 women     4
3 time2 men       6
4 time2 women     4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Would you also know how to produce a tibble that summarizes the count and percentages of both the sex variable and the hypert_drug variable? 

Grouping by both does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
questiondata %>%group_by(time,sex)%>% summarise(count = n(), .groups = "keep")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   time, sex [4]
  time  sex   count
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 time1 men       6
2 time1 women     4
3 time2 men       6
4 time2 women     4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
Would there also be a way to get the counts of sex ánd the 'hypert_drug' variable? If I group by both then it produces a tibble for every possible combination of sex and hypert_drug with time, which is not what I want.